# Problema com SUM na NamedQuery

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Tenho a seguinte `NamedQuery`:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Controle.listarTotais", query = "SELECT controle.prestador, controle.tipoPrestador, SUM(controle.valorLote), SUM(controle.valorPago), SUM(controle.valorGlosa) FROM Controle controle WHERE controle.competencia.codigo = :competencia GROUP BY controle.prestador ORDER BY controle.prestador  ")
```

Nela utilizo a função de agregação `SUM`. Faço a consulta dessa forma:

```
public List<Controle> listarTotais(String competencia) {
        List<Controle> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transacao = null;
        try {
            transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
            Query consulta = sessao.getNamedQuery("Controle.listarTotais");
            consulta.setString("competencia", competencia);
            lista = consulta.list();
            transacao.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

Essa consulta retorna uma lista de `Controle`, até ai tudo bem porém a lista vem em um formato diferente do esperado. O retorno dessa lista é um `Array` de `Arrays`e dentro desses Arrays cada índice corresponde a um item do objeto.

Exemplo:

```
Array [ Array[5], Array[5], Array[5], Array[5] ]
```

O Esperado seria isso:

```
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Quando retiro o `SUM` da `NamedQuery` funciona da forma esperada. Qual seria o possível problema e como posso resolve-lo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um construtor no `Controle` ou numa nova classe que receba os valores que você está retornando.

Ex.:

```
new Controle(Prestador pre, TipoPrestador tp, Float valorLote, Float valorPago, ... // resto dos atributos.
```

Ai na namedQuery usando o select new:

```
SELECT new Controle ( controle.prestador, controle.tipoPrestador, SUM(controle.valorLote), SUM(controle.valorPago), SUM(controle.valorGlosa) ) FROM Controle controle WHERE controle.competencia.codigo = :competencia GROUP BY controle.prestador ORDER BY controle.prestador
```

Comment: Obrigado, problema resolvido